# Delete Apple Arcade account

Tags: apple-id, game-center, apple-arcade

Multiple times I have logged out of Game Center, only to find that 2-3 days later, I'm (without consent) logged back into the account. Please see the image below:

[image: Fk Such Forced Behaviors]

---

At this point, I want to delete the Game Center account. Not only is this not for me, but the sly practice of unnecessarily logging in a person is a significant turn-off.

Can someone help me prevent these forced logins to the service, or even better - help me delete this parasitic Game Center account?

Comment: You appear to have over 100 bucks' credit on there - maybe it won't give up until you spend it or figure out how to get a refund… [I've never even signed into it, so this is pure guesswork]

Comment: @Tetsujin The credit is just the iTunes account balance.

Comment: @grg - ah, OK, then as in the answer, it's just another non-independent 'bit' of your Apple ID. Makes sense.

Comment: @Tetsujin: Like the other guy mentioned, this balance is unrelated to Apple Arcade/Game Center. This amount is used for my other subscriptions (iCloud, specifically). This balance existed before Game Center was even launched.

Comment: @Downvoter: Please explain.

Comment: @displayName Are you signing out of game center in Settings > Game Center? I believe your references to Apple Arcade are confusing people, since Game Center ≠ Apple Arcade

Comment: @Ezekiel: That's correct. I'm signing out of Game Center and Apple just logs me back in without asking.

Comment: @displayName In that case, I would advise removing all references to Apple Arcade from your question. As for why it's signing you back in, probably because you're signed into iCloud. The only purpose for the Sign Out button is to switch to different Game Center accounts after signing out... It's not a different account, so it's not really signing you back in to anything, per se

Comment: @displayName That being said, it does sound like a bug which would mean there's probably no solution here, but Game Center doesn't *do* anything unless you play games...

Answer (score 2):

Apple Arcade is not a separate account, it is a subscription you can purchase from on your regular Apple ID account (this is the same as an iTunes or iCloud account).

When you go to the Apple Arcade tab and tap your profile picture, you are simply seeing your Apple ID account details, regardless of whether you're an Apple Arcade subscriber or not. Every user sees this screen.

---

You can cancel your Apple Arcade subscription, but your account will continue to exist because it is **not specific to Apple Arcade**.

https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/subscribe-to-apple-arcade-iphc49263025/ios

> Change or cancel your Apple Arcade subscription
>
> Go to Settings > [your name] > Subscriptions, tap Apple Arcade, then follow the onscreen instructions.
>
> If you cancel your subscription, you can’t play any Apple Arcade games, even if you downloaded them to your device. Delete the apps if you don’t want them anymore.

---

Lastly, a note about Game Center: Game Center is a profile on your Apple ID specifically for game achievements, etc. **It is not related to Apple Arcade except that most Apple Arcade games have achievements, so they appear in Game Center.** You cannot delete a Game Center profile without deleting your Apple ID, since it's just another part of your standard Apple Account.